# How can I set an environment variable on bash on a function whose output will be piped?

Tags: bash, function, environment-variables, pipe

I have a bash script similar to the following

```
func() {
  echo "func was called"
  var="right"
}

var="wrong"
func
echo $var

var="wrong"
func | tee file
echo $var
```

Since func() sets var to "right", I would expect echo to print that string twice. However, I noticed that if a function's output is redirected through a pipe (and not through to a file using >), then the environment variables aren't set. In this case, the output is

```
right
func was called
wrong
```

Why is this happening? Is there any way I can have that function set environment variables, even if its output is redirected?

Answer (score 2):

If you run a command in a pipeline (that is, a sequence of simple commands separated by `|`), then the command is actually executed in a subshell. Since every shell has its own environment variables, and there is no relation between variable in different shells, you can't persist environment variables from commands run in a pipeline (on either side of the pipe).

In many cases, you can work around this issue by using [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). For example:

```
func > >(tee file)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to use of pipe before `tee` command which creates a sub shell to execute the commands. You make change to variable value in sub shell itself and when sub shell exits you get unchanged value in parent calling shell.